# Pass data from servlet to jsp without forms?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

So what I'm basically trying to do here is get a list of hotels in JSP , from the servlet , without any forms.

This is my JSP:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"  
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
    <c:forEach var="elem" items="${list}">
    <li>${elem.name}</li>
    </c:forEach>    
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Servlet function:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws                           ServletException, IOException {


    try {
        java.util.List<Hotel> list = model.getAllHotels();
        request.setAttribute("list", list);
        RequestDispatcher rDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
        rDispatcher.forward(request, response);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now I know how to do this via form with get / post , since the servlet has specific functions for that. But how can I send this data without forms ?

Comment: Why do you want to do it without forms?

Comment: Because I don't need forms to do the exact same things in PHP I guess. I'm just starting to learn jsp / servlets and it's a bit confusing.

That data is supposed to show on that page when you access it , without the user having to do any actions.

Comment: What data (name and value) you want to send without form?

Comment: I don't want to send data TO the servlet , I just need the servlet to send data TO the jsp , said data being the result of a query.

Comment: OK, but what is the query parameter? Is it some fixed ID or should it be dependent on something?

Comment: I edited the post ,this specific query has no parameter since it's a SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE 1.

It does not depend on anything.

Comment: Your edit seems to solve your problem, since now you don't need any input form client. Just go to URL which will request your servlet.

Comment: I realize how stupid this will sound , but how do I do that exactly ?

Comment: What address you would use in forms `action=...` attribute that would send data to your servlet? Is there any `@WebServlet("/yourServletsURL")` annotation at your servlet class or `<url-pattern>` in your `web.xml` (deployment-descriptor)?

Comment: I assume you mean this:
@WebServlet("/HotelController")

Comment: Yes. As JB Nizet said in his answer try `http://localhost:8080/yourWebApp/yourServlet` so in your case it will most probably be `http://localhost:8080/yourWebApp/HotelController`

Comment: @CataVisan: yes. In that case, the address of your servlet is `http://localhost:8080/yourWebApp/HotelController`

Comment: @CataVisan You can use a tag handler if you don't want to use jsp scriptlets inside your jsp. But dont write sql querying code in jsp. Delegate to a controller. That will be easier for debugging and make the code reusable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need a link to your servlet:

```
<a href="<c:url value='/yourServlet' />">Click here to list the hotels</a>
```

You can also invoke the servlet by typing its address in the address bar of your browser:

```
http://localhost:8080/yourWebApp/yourServlet
```

The code of your servlet is fine, and the code of the JSP as well.

The servlet is mapped to some URL (`/yourServlet` in my example) thanks to a `<servlet-mapping>` element in the web.xml, or thanks to a `@WebServlet` annotation on the servlet class.

Comment: This is pretty much what I need , but I need to get it done without the client having to click the link.

Comment: Well I agree this is the best approach. +1 . The request should be directed to the servlet instead of a jsp.

Answer (score -1):

The best way to do that is to use a Tag handler. You won't have to deal with the servlet.
Your jsp can invoke the tag handler and get the list of hotels and you can loop over the list, like you are doing in your code.

```
<c:set var="HotelList">
    <x:HotelSearch query="something" /> 
</c:set>
<c:set var="list" value="${fn:split(HotelList, ',')}" />
<ul>
    <c:forEach var="elem" items="${list}">
        <li>${elem.name}</li>
    </c:forEach>    
</ul>
```

In the above code `HotelSearch` is a tag handler created to return search results string.
e.g. hotel1,hotel2,hotel3

The string is later broken down using split and converted into an array.

```
public class HotelSearch extends SimpleTagSupport {

    private String query;

    @Override
    public void doTag() throws JspException {
        JspWriter out = getJspContext().getOut();
        try {
            //Query the database using a Database Controller.
            out.println(DatabaseController.getSearchResult(query));
        } catch (java.io.IOException ex) {
            throw new JspException("Error in HotelSearch tag", ex);
        }
    }

    public void setQuery(String query) {
        this.query = query;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd like to know the reason for the downvote. Since the OP is asking for search results directly from a java program and not servlet.

Comment: That's not at all what the OP is asking. Re-read the question. The architecture of the OP is a clean MVC architecture. You're suggesting to ruin this clean architecture by reading data from the database in the view, instead of doing it from the controller like the OP correctly does it.

Comment: BTW,@JBNizet wouldn't it be great if a database controller handles the querying the db part. Like I have shown in my tag handler. In that way  it would not expose the database to the view.

Comment: @JBNizet Whats wrong if a tag handler delegates the job of querying  the database to another controller. And passes the result back to the jsp. Is that breaking MVC?

Comment: Yes, because you already are in the view rendering phase when querying the database. If there is an error, you can't display a clean error page anymore. If you need validated parameters to make the query, you're forced to get them in the view instead of getting them in the controller, etc. etc.

Comment: Yeah, never thought about it. :). Thanks.