# pass Java servlet object into JSP file?

Tags: java, jsp

How to pass object in java servlet to JSP file?

[This post's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12033092/how-to-pass-an-object-from-the-servlet-to-the-calling-jsp) answer by Matthew Abbott seems easy, but I'm not able to get it to work. I must be missing something obvious.

In my java servlet:

```
 request.setAttribute("testData", "TEST");
 request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/myFile.jsp").include(request, response);
```

myFile.jsp is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML lang='en'>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>My Page</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
  <p>${testData}</p> 
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

But this simply displays `${testData}` rather than `TEST`.

If I change myFile.jsp as follows, it works fine, but I understand scriplets are discouraged:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML lang='en'>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>My Page</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
  <% 
     String testData = (String) request.getAttribute("testData");
     out.println(testData);
  %>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Does `${requestScope.testData}` work?

Comment: Nope, similar results

Comment: Can you try `forward` instead of `include`?

Comment: Sure, I tried it just now and same results. Does EL require a `getAttribute()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to your JSP:

```
 <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

JSTL also has a dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I think your uri is slightly off (I get a blank page). But, I did see a similar line in this post: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20501595/pass-data-from-servlet-to-jsp-without-forms?rq=1`, but it didn't make a difference.

Comment: I just think that the feature you're trying to use is part of JSTL. I googled the uri, probably old. <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%> is probably right. JSTL has a dependency as well.

Comment: Where should `<dependency.../>` get added?

Comment: If you're using maven then with your dependencies in your pom.xml. If not then get the jar file (jstl-1.2.jar) from http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info  and put it in your classpath /WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not using Maven. I'm coding everything by hand in a text editor.

Comment: Ok, so get the jar and put it in /WEB-INF/lib.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use EL which could be disabled. Try adding this to the page:

```
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
```

Comment: This makes the page go blank. No sure where I'm supposed to insert it, so I tried inserting inside `<body>` tags, as well as (separately) before `<!DOCTYPE...`